# Horizontal Scroll View

Tags: android

I have a horizontal scroll view, and inside I have a number of image views, they go across the screen and altogether are wider than the screen.

I've tried to scroll through them using touch, but nothing happens, am I missing something?

Comment: did you solve your previous issue about setting images?

Comment: no, no one has replied with a working answer

Comment: see your previous question use LinearLayout instead RelativeLayout

Comment: show us your xml where you are using horizontal scroll view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `HorizontalScrollView`, put a `LinearLayout` with orientation Horizontal and add ImageView to that `LinearLayout`